# How do I burn a bootable CD from a .toast file?

Tags: classic-mac-os, bootable-disk

I bought a used G3 couple of days ago and I want to reinstall Mac OS 9. I got the OS in .toast format. Any knows how I make that into bootable CD? Just burning with Disk Utility didn't work, although there might be a way to use that which I don't know.

Comment: There's a Mac disc burning app called Roxio Toast; that's probably what you need to use to work with a .toast file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, just use [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html) and burn the .toast file to a CD. That will create a bootable CD that will be usable on your G3.

[Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) is a free application for burning CDs/DVDs. I don't know if it supports .toast files, but give it a try if you don't have Toast, since it may save you from buying it. I couldn't find online documentation for it, so let me know how it works.

Comment: toast is like £60 and I couldn't find any trial or something. Ill try Burn. thanks !

Comment: @latusaki Yeah, unfortunately it isn't free...